# Retrieving sentence score based on values of words in a dictionary

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, sapply, stringi

**Edited** `df` and `dict`

I have a data frame containing sentences:

```
df <- data_frame(text = c("I love pandas", "I hate monkeys", "pandas pandas pandas", "monkeys monkeys"))
```

And a dictionary containing words and their corresponding scores:

```
dict <- data_frame(word = c("love", "hate", "pandas", "monkeys"),
                   score = c(1,-1,1,-1))
```

I want to append a column "score" to `df` that would sum the score for each sentence:

**Expected results**

```
                  text score
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     3
4      monkeys monkeys    -2
```

**Update**

Here are the results so far:

*Akrun's methods*

*Suggestion 1*

```
df %>% mutate(score = sapply(strsplit(text, ' '), function(x) with(dict, sum(score[word %in% x]))))
```

Note that for this method to work, I had to use `data_frame()` to create `df` and `dict` instead of `data.frame()` otherwise I get: `Error in strsplit(text, " ") : non-character argument`

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

                  text score
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     1
4      monkeys monkeys    -1
```

This does not accounts for multiple matches in a single string. Close to expected result, but not quite there yet.

*Suggestion 2*

I tweaked a bit one of akrun's suggestion in the comments to apply it to the edited post

```
cbind(df, unnest(stri_split_fixed(df$text, ' '), group) %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        summarise(score = sum(dict$score[dict$word %in% x])) %>% 
        ungroup() %>% select(-group) %>% data.frame())
```

This does not account for multiple matches in a string:

```
                  text score
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     1
4      monkeys monkeys    -1
```

*Richard Scriven's methods*

*Suggestion 1*

```
group_by(df, text) %>%
mutate(score = sum(dict$score[stri_detect_fixed(text, dict$word)]))
```

After updating all packages, this now works (although it does not account for multiple matches)

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: text

                  text score
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     1
4      monkeys monkeys    -1
```

*Suggestion 2*

```
total <- with(dict, {
  vapply(df$text, function(X) {
    sum(score[vapply(word, grepl, logical(1L), x = X, fixed = TRUE)])
  }, 1)
})

cbind(df, total)
```

This give the same results:

```
                  text total
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     1
4      monkeys monkeys    -1
```

*Suggestion 3*

```
s <- strsplit(df$text, " ")
total <- vapply(s, function(x) sum(with(dict, score[match(x, word, 0L)])), 1)
cbind(df, total)
```

This actually works:

```
                  text total
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     3
4      monkeys monkeys    -2
```

*Thelatemail's method*

```
res <- sapply(dict$word, function(x) {
  sapply(gregexpr(x,df$text),function(y) length(y[y!=-1]) )
})

cbind(df, score = rowSums(res * dict$score))
```

Note that I added the `cbind()` part. This actually match the expected result.

```
                  text score
1        I love pandas     2
2       I hate monkeys    -2
3 pandas pandas pandas     3
4      monkeys monkeys    -2
```

**Final answer**

Inspired by akrun's suggestion, here is what I ended up writing as the most `dplyr`-esque solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

bind_cols(df, unnest(stri_split_fixed(df$text, ' '), group) %>% 
            group_by(x) %>% mutate(score = sum(dict$score[dict$word %in% x])) %>% 
            group_by(group) %>% 
            summarise(score = sum(score)) %>% 
            select(-group))
```

Although I will implement Richard Scriven's suggestion #3 since it's the most efficient.

**Benchmark**

Here are the suggestions applied to much larger datasets (`df` of 93 sentences and `dict` of 14K words) using `microbenchmark()`:

```
mbm = microbenchmark(
  akrun = df %>% mutate(score = sapply(stri_detect_fixed(text, ' '), function(x) with(dict, sum(score[word %in% x])))),
  akrun2 = cbind(df, unnest(stri_split_fixed(df$text, ' '), group) %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(score = sum(dict$score[dict$word %in% x])) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-group) %>% data.frame()),
  rscriven1 = group_by(df, text) %>% mutate(score = sum(dict$score[stri_detect_fixed(text, dict$word)])),
  rscriven2 = cbind(df, score = with(dict, { vapply(df$text, function(X) { sum(score[vapply(word, grepl, logical(1L), x = X, fixed = TRUE)])}, 1)})),
  rscriven3 = cbind(df, score = vapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), function(x) sum(with(dict, score[match(x, word, 0L)])), 1)),
  thelatemail = cbind(df, score = rowSums(sapply(dict$word, function(x) { sapply(gregexpr(x,df$text),function(y) length(y[y!=-1]) ) }) * dict$score)),
  sbeaupre = bind_cols(df, unnest(stri_split_fixed(df$text, ' '), group) %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(score = sum(dict$score[dict$word %in% x])) %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(score = sum(score)) %>% select(-group)),
  times = 10
)
```

And the results:

[image]

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Comment: I guess you have to try `strsplit`.  Something like `sapply(strsplit(df$text, ' '), function(x) with(dict, sum(score[word %in% x])))`

Comment: @akrun. That dit the trick. `df %>%
mutate(score = sapply(strsplit(text, ' '), function(x) with(dict, sum(score[word %in% x]))))`

Comment: @akrun How could I then divide the resulting score by the distinct number of words that returned a match in the dictionary for a given sentence ?

Comment: You could get the distinct number of words by `sapply(strsplit(df$text, ' '), function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: Based on your info, you could also try `library(stringi); library(tidyr);  cbind(df, unnest(stri_split_fixed(df$text, ' '), group) %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(val= sum(dict$score[dict$word %in% x])/sum(dict$word %in% unique(x)))%>%ungroup() %>% data.frame())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update :** Here's the easiest `dplyr` method I've found so far. And I'll add a `stringi` function to speed things up. Provided there are no identical sentences in `df$text`, we can group by that column and then apply `mutate()`

Note: Package versions are dplyr 0.4.1 and stringi 0.4.1

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

group_by(df, text) %>%
    mutate(score = sum(dict$score[stri_detect_fixed(text, dict$word)]))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# Groups: text
#
#             text score
# 1  I love pandas     2
# 2 I hate monkeys    -2
```

I removed the `do()` method I posted last night, but you can find it in the edit history.  To me it seems unnecessary since the above method works as well and is the more `dplyr` way to do it.

Additionally, if you're open to a non-`dplyr` answer, here are two using base functions.

```
total <- with(dict, {
    vapply(df$text, function(X) {
        sum(score[vapply(word, grepl, logical(1L), x = X, fixed = TRUE)])
    }, 1)
})
cbind(df, total)
#             text total
# 1  I love pandas     2
# 2 I hate monkeys    -2
```

Or an alternative using `strsplit()` produces the same result

```
s <- strsplit(df$text, " ")
total <- vapply(s, function(x) sum(with(dict, score[match(x, word, 0L)])), 1)
cbind(df, total)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of double looping via `sapply` and `gregexpr`:

```
res <- sapply(dict$word, function(x) {
  sapply(gregexpr(x,df$text),function(y) length(y[y!=-1]) )
})
rowSums(res * dict$score)
#[1]  2 -2
```

This also accounts for when there is multiple matches in a single string:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("I love love pandas", "I hate monkeys"))
# run same code as above
#[1]  3 -2
```